# GKSession between different apps

Tags: iphone, gksession

I'm new to iPhone programming, and I have a question about Bluetooth I can't find an answer to.  I'm planning on having a number of different apps, and I want users to be able to chat with each other no matter which one they are using.  I know GKSessions make Bluetooth a lot easier, but I can't find out if you can use it between different apps.

I used Wei-Meng Lee's program ( http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954 ), and successfully tested between different devices.  I put the code into two different apps, but when the apps were built on two different devices, they both started their search protocols but couldn't find each other.

It seems like the documentation assumes the GKSessions are between the same app.  Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 1):

when using two different apps, mayb u are using different session ids. I tried the Wei Meng Lee's code in two different apps. I too had the same problem. But it got solved when i set the session id of both the devices to 'nil'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great idea, I am also very interested in finding a way to do this. Maybe the WiTap application by apple (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) could be modified to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with xcode 4.4, just create a `GKSession` with same `SessionID`, two apps can talk to each other.